# How does `max_features` limit the number of features in an sklearn ensemble model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I still do not entirely understand `max_features` in `sklearn` classifiers. The [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html) leaves a little bit of room open for interpretation. For the purposes of this question, suppose I am using a tree-based classifier, such as a decision tree, random forest, gradient boosting, etc.

If for example, I were to set `max_features=10`, does that mean that each estimator will randomly take 10 features from my dataset to build the entire tree, or does it mean that each time a node is being split, each estimator randomly samples 10 features and picks the one that reduces entropy the most?

It was my understanding that an individual estimator would limit itself to 10 variables for the entire process. However, it seems that the maximum number of features resets at each node. That is, for any given node, the estimator randomly selects 10 features, chooses the best one, splits the node and repeats the process for all subsequent nodes.

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(max_features=10, n_estimators=150)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, it seems that the maximum number of features resets at each node. That is, for any given node, the estimator randomly selects 10 features, chooses the best one, splits the node and repeats the process for all subsequent nodes.

Your understanding here is correct. The way both gradient boosting and random forests work is that at **each split** for each tree, they will randomly select `max_features` (in the literature, this parameter is called `mtry`) to evaluate. This is one of the mechanisms by which the model introduces randomness across models—by not evaluating every feature at every split.

Answer (score 2):

Complementary to Tgsmith61591 answer, if you dive deeper into the [code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf3/sklearn/ensemble/_gb.py#L771) you can find an additional comment which add some useful information on how the `max_features` hyperparameter works in the model:

> Notes
> -----
> The features are always randomly permuted at each split. Therefore,
> the best found split may vary, even with the same training data and
> `max_features=n_features`, if the improvement of the criterion is
> identical for several splits enumerated during the search of the best
> split. To obtain a deterministic behaviour during fitting,
> `random_state` has to be fixed.

Furthermore, the key concept is that random forests need to increase the randomness in order to decrease the variance of the model (although this may lead to higher bias), as it is warned in this final note:

> Note: the search for a split does not stop until at least one valid partition of the node samples is found, even if it requires to effectively inspect more than max_features features.